# How to use a string value in console output of upstream project as parameter for downstream project?

Tags: jenkins

I am building a pipeline(in jenkins), which runs two different projects.
I am new to Jenkins.

- The first project installs a software and returns the URL(ip:port) to access the software.
- The second build uses that URL as a parameter to run a smoke test on that software.

Is there any way we can get that URL from first project and parse it into second project as parameter?

Comment: Are you using pipelines jobs (i.e. Groovy syntax) or freestyle jobs ?

Comment: I am doing it as a freestyle job.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a file in the first job that will contain the url `url_var=xxx:8080` and archive the file. the second job will download the file and load the content with the envinject plugin  - https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin , so you will have an environment variable `url_var` with your url.

Comment: The URL will be in the console output of the first project. Can you please explain how to access that console log and then search for the URL using regex and then create a file which will contain that URL and then how to archive it?

Comment: if you can print it to console  , you can print it to a file it will much easier, than you have 2 options :
1 use it as a parameter for the second job
2. archive the file and read it in the second job

Comment: Thanks Mor, I ended up using groovy script in jenkins-pipeline.
Thank you for your suggestion though.